# TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape some LinkedIn profiles, however, using the code below, gives me an error:

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b6cfafdd5b52> in <module>
     25     #sending our driver as the driver to be used by srape_linkedin
     26     #you can also create driver options and pass it as an argument
---> 27     ps = ProfileScraper(cookie=myLI_AT_Key, scroll_increment=random.randint(10,50), scroll_pause=0.8 + random.uniform(0.8,1),driver=my_driver)  #changed name, default driver and scroll_pause time and scroll_increment made a little random
     28     print('Currently scraping: ', link, 'Time: ', datetime.now())
     29     profile = ps.scrape(url=link)       #changed name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrape_linkedin\Scraper.py in __init__(self, cookie, scraperInstance, driver, driver_options, scroll_pause, scroll_increment, timeout)
     37 
     38         self.was_passed_instance = False
---> 39         self.driver = driver(**driver_options)
     40         self.scroll_pause = scroll_pause
     41         self.scroll_increment = scroll_increment

TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
    from datetime import datetime
        from scrape_linkedin import ProfileScraper
        import random                       #new import made
        from selenium import webdriver  #new import made
        import pandas as pd
        import json
        import os
        import re
        import time
        
        os.chdir("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Dropbox\\linkedInScrapper\\")
        
my_profile_list = ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/christinelagarde/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/ursula-von-der-leyen/']
        
        myLI_AT_Key = MyKey # you need to obtain one from Linkedin using these steps:
    
    # To get LI_AT key
    # Navigate to www.linkedin.com and log in
    # Open browser developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I or right click -> inspect element)
    # Select the appropriate tab for your browser (Application on Chrome, Storage on Firefox)
    # Click the Cookies dropdown on the left-hand menu, and select the www.linkedin.com option
    # Find and copy the li_at value
        
        for link in my_profile_list:
        
            #my_driver = webdriver.Chrome()  #if you don't have Chromedrive in the environment path then use the next line instead of this
            #my_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            my_driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\MyUser\Dropbox\linkedInScrapper\geckodriver.exe')
            #my_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\MyUser\Dropbox\linkedInScrapper\chromedriver.exe')
            #sending our driver as the driver to be used by srape_linkedin
            #you can also create driver options and pass it as an argument
            ps = ProfileScraper(cookie=myLI_AT_Key, scroll_increment=random.randint(10,50), scroll_pause=0.8 + random.uniform(0.8,1),driver=my_driver)  #changed name, default driver and scroll_pause time and scroll_increment made a little random
            print('Currently scraping: ', link, 'Time: ', datetime.now())
            profile = ps.scrape(url=link)       #changed name
            dataJSON = profile.to_dict()
        
            profileName = re.sub('https://www.linkedin.com/in/', '', link)
            profileName = profileName.replace("?originalSubdomain=es", "")
            profileName = profileName.replace("?originalSubdomain=pe", "")
            profileName = profileName.replace("?locale=en_US", "")
            profileName = profileName.replace("?locale=es_ES", "")
            profileName = profileName.replace("?originalSubdomain=uk", "")
            profileName = profileName.replace("/", "")
        
            with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'ScrapedLinkedInprofiles', profileName + '.json'), 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(dataJSON, json_file)
                time.sleep(10 + random.randint(0,5))    #added randomness to the sleep time
            #this will close your browser at the end of every iteration
            my_driver.quit()
        
        
        
        print('The first observation scraped was:', my_profile_list[0:])
        print('The last observation scraped was:', my_profile_list[-1:])
        print('END')
```

I have tried a number of different methods to try and get `webdriver.Chrome()` to work, without any luck. I have tried with Chrome (chromedriver) and Firefox (geckodriver), a number of different way to try and load in the `selenium` package but I keep getting the error `TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not callable`.

My original code below, still works. (i.e. it opens a Google Chrome browser and goes to each of the profiles in `my_profiles_list` but I would like to use the code above.

```
from datetime import datetime
from scrape_linkedin import ProfileScraper
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
import re
import time

my_profile_list = ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/christinelagarde/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/ursula-von-der-leyen/']
# To get LI_AT key
# Navigate to www.linkedin.com and log in
# Open browser developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I or right click -> inspect element)
# Select the appropriate tab for your browser (Application on Chrome, Storage on Firefox)
# Click the Cookies dropdown on the left-hand menu, and select the www.linkedin.com option
# Find and copy the li_at value
myLI_AT_Key = 'INSERT LI_AT Key'
with ProfileScraper(cookie=myLI_AT_Key, scroll_increment = 50, scroll_pause = 0.8) as scraper:
    for link in my_profile_list:
        print('Currently scraping: ', link, 'Time: ', datetime.now())
        profile = scraper.scrape(url=link)
        dataJSON = profile.to_dict()
        
        profileName = re.sub('https://www.linkedin.com/in/', '', link)
        profileName = profileName.replace("?originalSubdomain=es", "")
        profileName = profileName.replace("?originalSubdomain=pe", "")
        profileName = profileName.replace("?locale=en_US", "")
        profileName = profileName.replace("?locale=es_ES", "")
        profileName = profileName.replace("?originalSubdomain=uk", "")
        profileName = profileName.replace("/", "")
        
        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'ScrapedLinkedInprofiles', profileName + '.json'), 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(dataJSON, json_file)
            time.sleep(10)
            
print('The first observation scraped was:', my_profile_list[0:])
print('The last observation scraped was:', my_profile_list[-1:])
print('END')
```

Notes:

The code is slightly different since I asked a question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65531036/adding-an-open-close-google-chrome-browser-to-selenium-linkedin-scraper-code/65535170#65535170) in which @Ananth helped give me a solution.

I am also aware that there are "similar" questions related to `selenium` and `chromedriver` online and SO but after trying each of the proposed solutions I still could not get it working. (i.e. a common solution is a typo in `webdriver.Chrome()`).

Comment: It looks like `ProfileScraper` may be expecting the driver class for the `driver` parameter, not an *instance* of the driver class. Try `ps = ProfileScraper(cookie=myLI_AT_Key, scroll_increment=random.randint(10,50), scroll_pause=0.8 + random.uniform(0.8,1), driver=webdriver.Firefox)`.

Comment: Also, never post API keys online. You may want to obtain a new key now.

Comment: Thanks, I think that may have fixed the issue! Additionally, the API key I put in the original post was a significantly cut down version of my original key but thanks for editing it out. Thanks again!

Comment: One issue with this solution (and it is a minor issue) - adding `driver=webdriver.Firefox` to the `ProfileScraper` function does not allow me to run the code `my_driver.quit()`. So, I have Firefox open for each profile I am looking at (i.e. it does not close the browser window when finished).

Comment: `ps.driver.quit()`, although that *may* mess with what the library is doing if they expect it to remain open.